# Shortcut to apply header style 4 (and 5, 6...)

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

In Microsoft Office Word, one can press <kbd>⌘⌥1</kbd>, <kbd>⌘⌥2</kbd> or <kbd>⌘⌥3</kbd> to apply header styles 1, 2 or 3 respectively. This is also [documented](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Word-keyboard-shortcuts-c0ca851f-3d58-4ce0-9867-799df73666a7?CorrelationId=a6a552ad-1945-41d3-bce1-abd587309ab4&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) by Microsoft (see: Aligning and formatting paragraphs). However writing a large document, I want to apply header style 4 (and 5, 6...) but there does not seem to be a shortcut available for that. Applying header styles is not an option in the menu bar, so I cannot create a custom shortcut through `System Preferences > Keyboard` (I suppose). How would I add a shortcut in this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it, although I did not expect the solution to be this simple. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Right-click the Heading 4 style in the ribbon and choose 'Modify' (Or through Layout > Styles > Heading 4 > Modify
2. In the left hand bottom corner, select 'Shortcut'
3. Assign shortcut <kbd>⌘⌥4</kbd>
4. Repeat for Heading 5, 6...
5. Done!

Comment: Cheers. It still worked after 12 years in 2024 on my Mac.